How to drop records after date based on condition
I'm looking for an elegant way to drop all records in a DataFrame that occur before the latest occurrence of 'TEST_COMPONENT' being 'UNSATISFACTORY', based on their 'TEST_DT' value for each ID.
For example, given the following DataFrame for ID 5000:
| ID   | TEST_ID | TEST_COMPONENT | TEST_DT                       |
|------|---------|----------------|-------------------------------|
| 5000 | ENGL    | SATISFACTORY   | 2023-01-04T00:00:00.000+11:00 |
| 5000 | ENGL    | SATISFACTORY   | 2022-09-07T00:00:00.000+10:00 |
| 5000 | OTHER   | NONE           | 2022-09-07T00:00:00.000+10:00 |
| 5000 | ENGL    | UNSATISFACTORY | 2016-05-23T00:00:00.000+10:00 |
| 5000 | OTHER   | NONE           | 2016-05-23T00:00:00.000+10:00 |
| 5000 | OTHER   | NONE           | 2016-05-23T00:00:00.000+10:00 |
| 5000 | OTHER   | NONE           | 2016-02-09T00:00:00.000+11:00 |
| 5000 | OTHER   | NONE           | 2016-02-09T00:00:00.000+11:00 |
| 5000 | OTHER   | NONE           | 2016-02-09T00:00:00.000+11:00 |
| 5000 | ENGL    | UNSATISFACTORY | 2014-05-29T00:00:00.000+10:00 |
| 5000 | OTHER   | NONE           | 2013-09-27T00:00:00.000+10:00 |

I would like to retain only the rows from the latest 'UNSATISFACTORY' record onward. The desired output for this example would be:
| ID   | TEST_ID | TEST_COMPONENT | TEST_DT                       |
|------|---------|----------------|-------------------------------|
| 5000 | ENGL    | SATISFACTORY   | 2023-01-04T00:00:00.000+11:00 |
| 5000 | ENGL    | SATISFACTORY   | 2022-09-07T00:00:00.000+10:00 |
| 5000 | OTHER   | NONE           | 2022-09-07T00:00:00.000+10:00 |
| 5000 | ENGL    | UNSATISFACTORY | 2016-05-23T00:00:00.000+10:00 |

How can I achieve this in an efficient manner utlizing PySpark?

Here is my attempt using Window function:
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("ID")

df = df.withColumn("MAX_DATE",F.max(F.when(df['TEST_COMPONENT']=='UNSATISFACTORY',df['TEST_DT']).otherwise(None)).over(window_spec))
df_drop = df.filter((df['TEST_DT']>F.col('MAX_DATE')) | ((df['TEST_DT']==F.col('MAX_DATE')) & (df['TEST_COMPONENT']=='UNSATISFACTORY')))

df_drop.show(truncate=False)


I achieved this by performing the following 3 steps in PySpark:
df_max = df.filter(col("TEST_COMPONENT")=="UNSATISFACTORY")\
.groupBy("ID")\
.agg(max("TEST_DT")\
.alias("LATEST_UNSAT"))

df = df.alias("a").join(\
  df_max.alias("b")\
  ,df.ID == df_max.ID\
  ,"left")

df = df.filter(col("TEST_DT") >= col("LATEST_UNSAT"))

This approach works, but I'm open to hearing better ideas.

There is one problem with this code, it also fetches the records that are of same date but  not UNSATISFACTORY

How about if we convert the column to timestamp and filter the data:
df = df.withColumn("TEST_DT", col("TEST_DT").cast("timestamp"))
latest_unsat_df = df.filter(col("TEST_COMPONENT") == "UNSATISFACTORY") \
                  .groupBy("ID") \
                  .agg(max("TEST_DT").alias("latest_unsat_dt"))

